# jQuery .each causing browser hangs

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to loop all my table rows and do some validations, below is my code.

```
$("#table > tr").each( function( idx, el ) {

// my calculations goes here, it will take 500 ms for each record        

});
```

This is working fine when I do loop for 20-30 rows, if I do loop  100+ records then browser hangs.

I am unable to use setTimeout here in this logic, could some one help me out on this. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: It would be helpful to see the calculations, 500ms is a lot of time.

Comment: Show your validations code .

Comment: 500ms * 100 rows = 50 sec. If I'm not mistaking most modern browsers allow JS to run for 30 sec uninterrupted, that require user confirmation. So you'd better optimize the validations to consume less time.

Comment: what is your calculations about?

Comment: I just have no idea how you could possibly write code that takes more than a couple ms to run... How do you *do* that?

Comment: It would be difficult for the community to help you with your question without seeing the calculations done for each record.  Please include a jsfiddle or code that you're using.

Comment: Is it possible to to have setTimeOut() in .each()  ?

Comment: @AmaraThota, why not, but you'd better optimise your validation. I feel you're doing something in a wrong way.

Comment: Can you place your "calculation" and tell us what you are trying to calculate?

Comment: Please give us Ur calculation which is talking 500ms from me it should not

Comment: Thank all, here is what am validating, 
I have a template section above my table, based on template selection I am populating table row values from local storage , while populating I am checking whether table row is already populated or not, if already filled I am not changing that value other wise I will load from local storage. (local storage has 1000 values)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can add `setTimeout`:

```
$("#table > tr").each( function( idx, el ) {

    setTimeout( function() { validation(idx,el) }, 0 );

});
```

But I'm pretty sure you're doing something in a wrong way inside you validation function. 500 ms of synchronous code is just too much in web development, especially for 30sec tasks! I'm sure you can do it asynchronously or more optimised.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but is that seTimeout stops executing .each()  untill we complete validation logic ?